# Proxy authentication with chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I’ve got one issue with chrome extension, I hope you can help me out to solve it. Here is the case.

I make an extension that will allow to change proxy servers with authentication credentials (user/password) on the fly.

I use `chrome.proxy.settings` to change the current proxy and listen for the  `webRequest.onAuthRequired` event. When the server requests authentication, I pass the username and password obtained by parsing the proxy URL.

```
async function setProxy(proxy) {
    proxy = new URL(proxy)
    var config = {
        mode: 'fixed_servers',
        rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: proxy.hostname,
                port: parseInt(proxy.port),
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"],
        }
    }
    chrome.proxy.settings.set(
        {
            value: config,
            scope: "regular",
        },
        function () { }
    )
    var myCredetails = { username: proxy.username, password: proxy.password }
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        function (details, callbackFn) {
            console.log(myCredetails)
            console.log("onAuthRequired!", details, callbackFn);
            callbackFn({
                authCredentials: myCredetails
            });
        },
        { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
        ['asyncBlocking']
    );
}
```

My problem is that when launching the extension, the browser can only authenticate correctly to the first proxy passed to this `setProxy` function.

I log the transmitted credentials and the handler launch, and in the console, the first successful authentication looks like this:

```
background.js[52] 11:11:11 - {username: '11111', password: '11111'}
background.js[52] 11:11:11 - onAuthRequired! {challenger: {…}, documentLifecycle: 'active', frameId: 0, frameType: 'outermost_frame', initiator: 'chrome-extension://jkdijjjobdgdconmccahccapedgncolo', …} ƒ (response) {
        webRequestInternal.eventHandled(
            eventName, subEventName, requestId, webViewInstanceId, response);
}
```

Later, after a certain time, a different proxy URL is passed to the `setProxy` function. The proxy is changed in the settings, the `webRequest.onAuthRequired` event handler is triggered, but this time, authentication does not happen correctly and enters into a loop. In the logs, it looks like this:

```
background.js[52] 11:13:00 - {username: '11111', password: '11111'}
background.js[52] 11:13:00 - onAuthRequired! {challenger: {…}, documentLifecycle: 'active', frameId: 0, frameType: 'outermost_frame', initiator: 'chrome-extension://jkdijjjobdgdconmccahccapedgncolo', …} ƒ (response) {
        webRequestInternal.eventHandled(
            eventName, subEventName, requestId, webViewInstanceId, response);
}
background.js[52] 11:13:01 - {username: '22222', password: '22222'}
background.js[52] 11:13:01 - onAuthRequired! {challenger: {…}, documentLifecycle: 'active', frameId: 0, frameType: 'outermost_frame', initiator: 'chrome-extension://jkdijjjobdgdconmccahccapedgncolo', …} ƒ (response) {
        webRequestInternal.eventHandled(
            eventName, subEventName, requestId, webViewInstanceId, response);
}
background.js[52] 11:13:02 - {username: '11111', password: '11111'}
background.js[52] 11:13:02 - onAuthRequired! {challenger: {…}, documentLifecycle: 'active', frameId: 0, frameType: 'outermost_frame', initiator: 'chrome-extension://jkdijjjobdgdconmccahccapedgncolo', …} ƒ (response) {
        webRequestInternal.eventHandled(
            eventName, subEventName, requestId, webViewInstanceId, response);
}
```

As I see in the logs, when changing the proxy, for authentication, login and password are passed not only from the current proxy but also from the one passed before. i.e., login/password from the current and previously passed onAuthRequired data start alternating.

Based on this, I have a strong feeling that something has been done wrong in terms of transferring the username /password to the onAuthRequired handler, that the data transferred to it is cached somewhere and, when triggered again, it is taken not only from what I am transmitting at the moment but also from somewhere else. And because of this, it gets into a cycle of incorrect authentication.

Somewhere on the forums, I read that to obtain login/password before passing it to the onAuthRequired handler, it is necessary to use a Promise, which is the correct way of authentication, as the code stops executing until the promise is fulfilled. Using a callback function (which the Chrome API uses and which I am currently using) does not achieve that.
Please help me figure it out... What am I doing wrong and what in my code leads to the fact that when I change the proxy, I get into a cycle of incorrect authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Did I not take into account that every time I installed a proxy, I simultaneously installed a NEW authorization handler `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener`? However, the OLD handlers have not gone away; they continue to hang and be called at every authorization. After all, I didn’t bother to remove the old handlers using `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.removeListener`, but I should have!

We had to rewrite everything so that the `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener` handler was installed only once during the entire life of the background process `background.js`, or first remove the old handlers before installing new ones.